# Why do I have only 4 new devices added after adding support for x86?

Tags: android, google-play, android-x86

The reason I'm asking this question is because I think this might be red flag and want to check, just in case.

I have a Unity project (but there's nothing specific to Unity in the question, so I don't add the tag). Previously, it was built for arm only, and when I uploaded it to Google play, "Native platforms" property said **armeabi-v7a**. Now I switched to a build that supports both arm and x86 architectures, and the "Native platforms" says "armeabi-v7a, **x86**".  However, the "Supported Android devices" property has a comment "4 added".

Shouldn't the amount of devices that were added because of a new architecture be bigger? Is this amount reported by google true, and if it is, why?

Comment: Other phones may have their own restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the Intel based Android devices that are commercialized not only support x86 but also armeabi-v7a (through an emulation layer).

That's why adding x86 binaries to your app only added 4 devices to your list. But by doing so, you greatly improved your support for all the x86 devices that were only "compatible" before.